# Is it possible to manually register to Firebase Cloud Messaging?

Tags: android, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have used old GoogleCloudMessaging register() method which is now deprecated. I have started migration to FCM, and need to change some old legacy code.

Previous version of GCM allowed us to choose time, when app should be registered - for example user was successfully logged in. Now the registration is done in the background and we are only receiving callback.

Is it possible to manually register to Firebase Cloud Messaging using non-deprecated API?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the google-services-gcm library is not deprecated and gives you the opportunity to call InstanceID.getToken at a time of your choosing.

The new and recommended FCM client library (firebase-messaging) does automatically register the application instance and provides a callback once the token is retrieved, however it is still up to your application logic what you would like to do with that token. So even if a user is not successfully logged in, you can ignore the generated token.

Comment: It's not deprecated, but it will be!. Don't go for it.